# "Выпилил" — подскажите проверочное слово

Tags: орфография, однокоренные-слова

Подскажите, пожалуйста, проверочное слово к слову **выпилил**.

Comment: @хоооо, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Вполне подойдёт **пилка**.

Answer (score 0):

Спил, выпИливание, пИльщик, пИлит, лесопИлка, пИлочка, спИлка, отпИлок, напИльник, вы[над-, от-, за-, пере-, про-, под-, с-]пИливать...
[**Пилить. Однокоренные слова**](http://cognates.ru/words/p/word22615)